# Inconsistent Javascript behaviour (IF statement nested in while loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, while-loop

I'm trying to write a simple Javascript(jQuery) function that randomly displays 6 Divs out of a possible 11. The code sort-of-works, it does randomly display around about half of the Divs, but it varaies between 4 and 8.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? It seems it should be so simple yet I'm completely lost!

My code:

```
<div class="offer">Offer 1</div>
<div class="offer">Offer 2</div>
... snip
<div class="offer">Offer 11</div>

<script src="query.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


 <script>
            var changed = 0;

            while (changed < 6) {


                $('.offer').each(function(index) {

                    if (changed < 6) {

                        var showOrNot = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

                        if (showOrNot == 1) {

                            $(this).addClass('offershow');
                            changed += 1;
                            $(this).text(changed); //debugging looking for the current value of changed 
                        }


                    }


                })


            }

        </script>
```

Comment: Works pretty well when I test it - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/LX5xC/ It will occasionally do less than 6 because there's no check to make sure it doesn't change the same div twice.

Comment: why are you outputting the divs in the first place, shouldn't this be a serverside/db job ?

Comment: Ah, *that* is what I hadn't accounted for. Thank you! Think Luke is probably right and a more 'exact' solution may be better, however.

Comment: ps Val: I'd very much prefer to do this server-side - and indeed my skills are more suited to that - but alas ...politics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem as it stands now is that you have a bunch of unrelated attempts. If you have a bucket with 11 balls and have a 50% chance to remove each ball, you could end up with any number of balls between 0 and 11. Probability is skewed toward the center, but you don't get six and exactly six each time.

What you want is to remove six, and exactly six, balls, selected arbitrarily.

Try something more like this:

```
var offers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
    // choose a remaining offer at random
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * offers.length);

    // retrieve the item being shown
    var item = $('.offer').eq(offers[index]);
    item.addClass('offerShow');

    // remove this offer from the list of possibilities
    offers.splice(index, 1);
}
```

*EDIT*: In the comments, the OP clarified that what he really wants is to take an arbitrarily-sized list of offers and show six of them. The code provided below addresses that need, rather than the strict request in the original question. I'm leaving the original code for reference.

```
var OFFERS_TO_SHOW = 6;  // config, of sorts

// make sure no offers are shown now
$('.offer').removeClass('offerShow');

// show offers selected at random
for (var i = 0; i < OFFERS_TO_SHOW; i += 1) {
    // get a list of offers not already being shown
    var candidates = $('.offer').not('.offerShow');

    // select one from this list at random
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * offers.length);

    // show this offer by adding the offerShow class
    candidates.eq(index).addClass('.offerShow');
}
```

Comment: In the comments, I'm seeing a lot of discussion about the initial state before this code runs. I don't think that's the crux of your problem, but you can easily set initial state simply by removing the class from all offers at the outset: `$('.offer').removeClass('offerShow');`

Comment: I think this is certainly the way to go. Not too sure how to implement it with jQuery's each, but I'm sure I'll find a way. Thank you!

Comment: Will read and reply to your comment later this evening. Thanks again!

Comment: Why do you need jQuery's each at all?

Comment: @Jack you won't be able to use `each()` since that's only to run the sequence exactly as many times as you have elements, not as many as you need. You can get your collection length with `$('.offer').length` and access the element directly with `$('.offer')[i]`.

Comment: I'm no jQuery or JavaScript expert, but this seems a little inefficient. You could use slice to remove the selected index from the offers array instead of doing two slice calls and a concat call. You're also re-running a full jQuery selector on all objects with the class of "offer" 6 times, before filtering it to "eq(index)". You could probably save out the jQuery selection of "offer" items before you run the for loop and then just filter it with eq inside the loop.

Comment: I'm running through jQueries each since there may at some later stage be an unknown number of 'offer' divs. 

The key that I was looking for is definitely to remove the 'offer' class when I'm adding 'offershow' - making the 'each' loop a bit less inefficient and also making sure I don't apply the class twice to any div, therefore getting the right number each time. Thanks all!

Comment: @Wesley: Yeah, it occurs to me that you could use `Array.splice`. I'll edit appropriately. Honestly, though, the bigger rationale is readability -- the I/O is so much slower than the array manipulation that the inefficiency aspect is not relevant. :)

Comment: @Jack: Provided is updated code for an arbitrarily sized list of offers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're not excluding divs that you've already set to show. So it's possible that your code to pick the next div to show is choosing one that's already been shown. If that makes sense? Trying changing your selector.....

```
$('.offer').not('.offershow').each(........
```

Keep in mind that addClass doesn't remove the existing classes, so your original selector will still prove true even though you've added the offershow class.

Comment: Thank you - this is what I'm going with. Luke did get there first in a comment hence the accepted answer...

Comment: No worries, he certainly gave a more detailed response and answer and you could've gone either way. :) Thanks for commenting though!

Answer (score 0):

You're actually not checking wheter the selected div is already shown or not. Means when you're looping through all divs, there is always a possibility of setting a div visible twice. The script now thinks it was a new one and sets changed += 1;

Try adding something like this:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('offershow')) {
    [[rest of code here]]
}
```